# Azure Redis Slow Log Repetative Errors "EVALSHA"

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

We are experiencing a tremendous amount of time outs using Redis Cache on Azure.

When we run the slow log, we see lots of the following.

Can anyone tell me why it is recording these to the slow log? Some are repeating, with only the indexes changing.

*currently there are 128 entries in the slow log, here is entry 127*

```
127) 1) (integer) 14861
     2) (integer) 1442222183
     3) (integer) 245171
     4) 1) "EVALSHA"
        2) "71fe2e7962348b06aa8ce3e244cdb3f774b4f549"
        3) "3"
        4) "WebApp_xhi5kymupxniuo2w2jrqjbns_Write_Lock"
        5) "WebApp_xhi5kymupxniuo2w2jrqjbns_Data"
        6) "WebApp_xhi5kymupxniuo2w2jrqjbns_Internal"
        7) "635777973834669806"
        8) "110"
```

The only difference between the entries is the asp.net session Id (WebApp_xhi5kymupxniuo2w2jrqjbns in the example above)

How can I determine what is causing this to be recorded into the slow log?

I have searched extensively throughout the web and tried numerous different "time out settings" without luck.

Comment: Is your WebApp and Redis cache in the same data center?

Comment: Yes it is. Both are in Azure West US.

Comment: Can you add your Lua script to the question?

Comment: We are not using any Lua scripts, we are just using it as our SessionState Provider. i.e. Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider

Answer (score 1):

Redis is logging these because they take more time than the slowlog-log-slower-than configuration parameter. 
Because this is related to your session one relevant thing that you could do is put less things there, especially the big items and start caching them separately. If you store big items, like search results, in session, they will be loaded on every page load and then send back to Redis after you finish processing with that page. This leads to a lot of traffic between your web server and Redis, keys being loaded even if they aren't needed and saved again even if they didn't change. Caching them separately to the same Redis instance means you can load them only when you need them. 
Of course you can also use a more powerfull machine.

Comment: thanks for the information. We do store some larger objects in Session. When you say "store them separately", can you elaborate? I assume you mean use Cache("Param1") vs. Session("Param1") - is that assumption accurate, or did you mean something else? TIA

Comment: Yes, I mean use the Redis directly, not through the Session object, so use RedisClient.Set(key, value) instead of Session[key] = value. We also used to put big items in Session and when we moved to Redis Session we started getting timeouts. But we caught it early in our dev, moved all the big objects in Redis directly with expiration and we don't have anymore problems. And it kind of gets you thinking how ineffective session really is :)